# How do I calculate the cost of GPT-4 Embeddings correctly?

Tags: python, token, openai-api, openaiembeddings

so I wrote the following code:

1. I have the number of tokens.
2. I looked up the [price](https://openai.com/pricing#language-models):

> gpt-4 $30.00 / 1M tokens

```
def print_embedding_cost(texts):
    import tiktoken
    enc = tiktoken.encoding_for_model('gpt-4')
    total_tokens = sum([len(enc.encode(page.page_content)) for page in texts])
    print(f'Total Tokens: {total_tokens}')
    print(f'Embedding Cost in USD: { (30 / 1_000_000) * total_tokens}')
    
print_embedding_cost(chunks)
```

Thinking: 30 USD for 1 Million tokens = price per token.
Somehow this results into a very high price, which isn't correct.

Comment: There's no [mcve] so it's impossible to tell what the multiplier is